# Why different string is matching to the pattern?

Tags: java, regex

I am using java 1.7.

I expect:

```
Pattern ddmmyyyyPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2}[- /.]\\d{1,2}[- /.]\\d{4})");
```

should match strings with atleast 2 occurences of seperators -/.
But, the following are matching

```
07 2.3180, 45 3.3183, 19 4.3183, 77 5.3025, 25 6.3023.
```

Also, 9507 2.31 is matching to

```
Pattern yyyymmddPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}[- /.]\\d{1,2}[- /.]\\d{1,2})");
```

Please help me in rectifying the pattern!

Comment: matching a pattern is not like doing an equals check: there can be several values that match the pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That happend because the character class also matches a space.

You could use a capturing group with a backreference to match a `date like` pattern. Note that is does not validate a date itself.

```
\d{1,2}([-/.])\d{1,2}\1\d{4}
```

About the pattern

- `\d{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 digits
- `([-/.])` Capture in a group matching - / or .
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1 or 2 digits
- `\1` Backreference to what is captured in group 1 (So 12/12-2019 will not match)
- `\d{4}` Match 4 digits

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\d{1,2}([-/.])\\d{1,2}\\1\\d{4}";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SNkMLD/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/wPN12i)

Note that for a match you can omit the outer parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove space from character class

```
\\d{1,2}[- /.]\\d{1,2}[- /.]\\d{4}
           ^             ^
```

change to this

```
\\d{1,2}[-/.]\\d{1,2}[-/.]\\d{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
\d{1,2}([-\/.])\d{1,2}([-\/.])\d{4}
```

Of course the blank space should be removed from the regex, and the character "/" needs to have a backslash before it in order it to be recognized.